# Should I implement a checksum process for the data transmited through serial port using Pyserial?

Tags: python-2.7, checksum, arduino-uno, pyserial

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I'm still learning English. So I implore you your tolerance.

I'm working on a project where I need to receive data from USB serial port using Python (Pyserial library especifically). An arduino sends me the data through a serial cable and then I receive it from a COM port.

I'm currently implementing a basic checksum process to verify that the transmited data arrive complete. From the arduino I add the value of the data I am transmiting and set to checksum field, wich will be transmited too. Then, on the computer, I perfomr the same operation over the data and verify that the sum is equal to the value of the checksum field.

My question is. Should I worry about this or that task is already performed by USB protocol?

If someone could give me some reference, it would be very helpful for me.

This is how currently I am calculating the checksum:

```
{
    s1: 425.2,
    s2: 426.4,
    s3: 78.2,
    s4: 785.2,
    chksum: 1715
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB does not correct the serial data. It is just a [bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)#External_bus) that the CPU uses to talk to the serial port with. You idea of adding some checksum to the protocol that you use to talk between the Arduino and PC is good and sound idea.

A very common hardware protocol used by serial ports is the RS232. It contains some support for error detection using a [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) bit. If the parity bit isn't correct the received byte will just be thrown away. So I don't think it would be much help in you case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will keep that in mind. I can not vote because I still have no reputation.